# what is icon index?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to programmatically creating a Shell link, i.e. a shortcut. In Visual Studio C++.

The shortcut is created, and it works. But the icon is the default one (because the provided icon was not taken in account by the API). Reading the docs, it appears that I have to provide a icon *index*. But what is this? For now there is only a .ico file.

Here is the code (see the ### lines)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ShlObj.h>

class MakeLnk
{

   public:
      MakeLnk(){}
      void SetLnkInfos
     (
     std::wstring i_target,
     std::wstring i_args,
     std::wstring i_savePath,
     std::wstring i_description,
     std::wstring i_icoloc
     )
  {
     target = i_target;
     args = i_args; 
     savePath = i_savePath;
     description = i_description;
     icolocation = i_icoloc;
  }

  // Utility function, to create a link
  HRESULT CreateLnk()
  {
     LPCWSTR lpszPathObj = target.c_str();
     LPCTSTR arguments = args.c_str();
     LPCWSTR lpszLinkPath = savePath.c_str();
     LPCWSTR lpszDesc = description.c_str();
// ##########################
     LPCWSTR lpszIcoPath = icolocation.c_str(); // a path like "C:\\tmp\\crab.ico"
// ##########################

     HRESULT hres;
     IShellLink* psl;
     CoInitialize(NULL);
     // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
     // has already been called.
     hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl);
     if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
     {
        IPersistFile* ppf;

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add description and args. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj);
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc);
        psl->SetArguments(arguments);
// ###############################################
        psl->SetIconLocation(lpszIcoPath, 0); // HERE! WHAT TO PUT INSTEAD OF "0" ?
// ###############################################
        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
        {
           // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
           hres = ppf->Save(lpszLinkPath, TRUE);
           ppf->Release();
        }
        psl->Release();
     }
     CoUninitialize();
     return hres;
  }

private:
  std::wstring target, args, savePath, description;
  std::wstring icolocation;
};


int main()
{
    MakeLnk linkMaker;
    std::wstring exepath(L"C:\\Program Files\\Crab\\Exec.exe"), arguments(L"eat dance"), lnkPath(L"shortcut.lnk"), description(L"Click here to lanch the crab program"), icon(L"C:\\tmp\\crab.ico");
    linkMaker.SetLnkInfos(exepath, arguments, lnkPath, description, icon);
    bool res = linkMaker.CreateLnk();
    return res ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Icons are stored in the resource data of the executable file.  There can be more than 1, the index selects which one you want.  If you use a .ico file instead of the embedded icon then the index is not relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, but here the icon is provided by an external .ico file. Not embedded into the executable.

Comment: If you don't like what it looks like then pick another .ico file.

Comment: @HansPassant Edited the question. I meant, the SetIconLocation method failed.

Comment: How do you know it failed?  You are not checking its return value.  A path like c:\tmp is not a healthy one for a .ico file that needs to be around for as long as the shortcut exists.  Be aware that Explorer caches icons, if it ever saw that shortcut with a different icon (or none at all) then you'll see the old one.  Google "windows reset shell icon cache" for hits.

Comment: @HansPassant Because the icon created is a very simple one. Manually, I can set the icon in the shortcut properties, to the new one. And, yes, "C:\\tmp\\crab.ico" was just an example.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry. Done.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine with *.ico file, it sets the icon and everything. I am using Windows 10. Do error check for `SetIconLocation` and `GetLastError`, maybe it's invalid icon path or something.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Okay so after extracted a MCVE, it worked immediately. Suspecting a problem with the original icon file, I tested with another, and also worked. Finally, retried with the first .ico, and..it worked! Don't understand, but that is. Also cleaned the cache as suggested by Hans, but still same result. And as pointed by Roger, the index for .ico should be "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell links can get their icons from EXE and DLL files, where they're stored as embedded resources. Since an EXE or DLL file can contain multiple icons, the shell link needs to know which one to use. That's controlled by the index.

ICO files (if I recall correctly) can contain only one icon.

Answer (score 3):

Windows executables can have so-called *resources*. One type of resource is an icon. An executable therefore can contain 0, 1 or more icons. If you need the second icon in your executable, use icon index 1 (they're numbered from 0, as usual)

If you have a .ico file, it **must** be added to your executable first, before you can use it. [`SetIconLocation` only works on executables (and DLL's)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/179904/how-to-change-the-icon-of-a-shortcut-through-ishelllink)

Comment: Thank you for the link. But how do you add the .ico to the executable?

Comment: @yO_ that is a new question that should be asked separately

Comment: I think this should work for all icon files including *.ico, *.icl, *.exe, *.dll, *.exe. The index for `SetIconLocation` applies to non *.ico files. It should work for *.ico file with index 0.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: That contradicts the MSDN documentation: "the file containing the icon (in this case the file is either a .dll or .exe)". Either...or... is a limitative list: those 2 and no others.

Comment: I tried the code in Windows 10, it works with *.ico file. Also if you try to change the change the icon manually it gives you a choice between *.ico, *.icl, *.exe and *.dll. The documentation is a bit vague, or maybe it's OS dependent.